# MongoSocketOpenException and ConnectException when dockerizing the MongoDB with SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, exception

I used Spring initializer to bootstrap the SpringBoot Application. Then I am using Docker Desktop also. I need to dockerize the integration of MongoDB with SpringBoot. My docker-compose.yml file is this,

```
version: '4.14.2'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: nim  #<my docker desktop username>
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123 #<my docker desktop password>

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: nim
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://nim:123@mongo:27017/
```

`application.properties` :

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=nimasha #<my MongoDB username>
spring.data.mongodb.password=1234 #<my MongoDB password>
spring.data.mongodb.database=StudentDBDocker
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

**Exception:**

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:535) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:585) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:82) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

mongo-express GUI is running properly as below,

[image: mongo-express]

Comment: Your Spring configuration says `spring.data.mongodb.username=nimasha` but the docker configuration says: `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: nim`. Looks like a mismatch?

Comment: nimasha is the username of mongodb cluster and nim is the username of docker desktop @ErikFinnman

Comment: At least according to the docs here https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo, `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` is the mongodb username.

Comment: @ErikFinnman  I changed according to the way how you are telling me. No, any change happened

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the docker container? Does it starta properly? Do you have local firewall which might interfere?

Comment: Yes docker desktop is running properly.  Wait i will upload an image of it also